# How can a DIV act like another element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

My skills in Javascript are limited and for practicing i'm trying to programatically fill some elements using JS code, using Chrome's Developer Tools. I navigate to a site, access the console and try to manipulate DOM elements using JS code.

Usually elements a user can input data are INPUT, TEXTAREA , SELECT and so on. But latelly i've been seeing elements that are user-editable, but are simply DIVs. In other words, a DIV acting like an INPUT or TEXTAREA, and this got me confused.

Here is an example : i extracted this source from a page to post topics in a Facebook Group.

Note that the div that has the 'Write something' innerhtml works as a textarea in the page. You can reproduce this code in any Facebook Group, ie https://www.facebook.com/groups/914737511952904/ (you might need to join the group before see the box to post a topic).

```
<div class="_1mwp _1mwq _5bu_ _5yk1"><div class="_5yk2" tabindex="-2">
 <div class="_5rp7">
   <div class="_1p1t">
    <div class="_1p1v" id="placeholder-   2bc29">Write something... </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If this element was a TEXTAREA, i could easily do something like

```
 document.getElementById('elementId').value = 'New text';
```

But the 'textarea' element in the above case is actually a DIV and nothing else.

How can i insert text on it using JS ? An how can a DIV act like a textarea or an input ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How can I insert text on it using JS?**

That's quite simple. Just use the `innerHTML` property to assign the text value.

```
document.getElementById('elementId').innerHTML = "Text inserted"
```

However you can do the same using just CSS, and then retrieving the text from the div invoking the same property.

**How can a DIV act like a textarea or an input?**

A very practical way is using the `contentEditable` property over the div, but you can use CSS styles as well, and in some cases with some JavaScript code.

You have a simple example here using CSS styles and `contentEditable` property:
https://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/AbKTQ/

Comment: Thank you, i did not know a DIV could be user editable :D

Answer (score 1):

> How can I insert text on it using JS?

```
element.textContent = "text content"
```

### SNIPPET 1

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

div.textContent = "line of text by textContent"
```

```html
<div></div>
```

> An how can a DIV act like a textarea or an input?

You can add `contneteditable` to an element that's not originally editable.

```
 <div contenteditable></div>
```

See Snippet on how to set `contenteditable` by JS

### SNIPPET 2

```js
var editor = document.querySelector('div');

editor.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
```

```html
<div>This is a div. Click on me and start typing.</div>
```